# A word or expression similar to "handmade"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I would like to open my own store with leather sandals, and accessories such as necklaces, rings, bracelets, scarves, etc. I would like to know if there is any other suitable word than "handmade".

I want a strong word, a word that would make somebody who sees it, to cause wonder. Or even a small expression will do. The logo of the store will be the letter K (from my name).

From all the stuff I mentioned, some will be handmade but some will also be hand crafted. The store will be in a Greek island, if that can be a blink of inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

***[Artisanal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/artisanal)*** may convey the idea of someting made  by hand :

> - pertaining to or noting a high-quality or distinctive product made in small quantities, usually by hand or using traditional methods.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: thank you do much for your answer. "sounds" lovely in my ears!

Comment: "Artisanal" is a very trendy word at the moment (often applied to a cup of coffee for example!), which isn't a bad thing per se, but things which are very fashionable run the risk of becoming very unfashionable, although this process probably happens more slowly on a Greek island :)  It's still probably the best word.